# Returning AlertDialog from Standard Java Class

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am currently working on an android project. I am trying to have an alert dialogue in a standard java class so that the code can be re-used throughout the app.

However, it is returning the alertdialog from the class back to the activity but when I attempt to show the alert dialog it displays the following error:

> Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

Below is the code that I have used to create the alert dialogue

```
public AlertDialog showAlertDialog(String message, Context context) 
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setMessage("hello")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        return alert;
    }
```

Below is the code from the android activity where I am trying to show the alert dialog

```
Common cla = new Common();
AlertDialog alert = cla.showAlertDialog("Hello", getApplicationContext());
alert.show();
```

Common is the name of the class

Comment: May be you can try yourActivity.this instead of context while creating AlertBuilder.

Comment: Thanks that worked, could you make that as an answer please so that way I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please chage your AlerDialogCreation logic to `AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(yourActivity.this);`